# Building dependent picklist by finding associated rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a need for a dependent picklists. The outputted workbook is actually created programmatically which does restrict the way this needs to be built (I'm trying to create everything in Excel first and then finish the programmatic output of the sheet).

I have rows that need dropdowns representing Objects and Fields in a database. So dropdown1 would contain a list of Objects and dropdown2 depends on that to display a list of Fields based on that object.

I have a Ledger sheet containing the data that needs to be represented. Something like this:

```
| A      | B      | C             |
|--------|--------|---------------|
| People | People | First Name    |
| Places | People | Last Name     |
| Things | People | Phone Number  |
|        | People | Email Address |
|        | Places | Longitude     |
|        | Places | Latitude      |
|        | Things | Color         |
|        | Things | Shape         |
```

The A column contains all the Objects (People, Places, Things) and is used to populate all the dropdown1's. The B & C columns are used to represent the fields - B being the Object the field belongs to and C being the FieldName. So if I choose People in dropdown1 I want dropdown 2 to contain only values from C that apply to People (First Name, Last Name, Phone Number, Email Address)

I'm struggling to make this work. In another sheet I have succeeded in listing out the values that I would want in dropdown2 using the following formula (where A2 refers to dropdown1) - `=IFERROR(INDEX(Ledger!C2:C1000,SMALL(IF(A2=Ledger!B2:B1000, ROW(Ledger!C2:C1000)-1,""), ROW()-1)), "")` - but I haven't been able to actually make this work when creating a dropdown (via Data Validation button in excel). How can I get this into a dropdown in excel?

Comment: You can do this with a combination of `Indirect`, Named Ranges, and data validation lists

Comment: Check [this article](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html)